# Issue on using bootstrap modal as adult content warning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a content warning for a wordpress site project with some potentially mature contents. I tried using bootstrap modal which is called by jquery, but the problem is it only overlays the page when the whole page itself gets done loading.

It kills the purpose since the page will load first unblocked by the overlay.

I want to ask if there is a way to load and open the bootstrap modal **before** the page content/body starts loading. Or if there isn't any advisable ways on using the modal for such purpose, what are my possible alternatives? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility with jQuery would include wrapping your current web page inside a `.page-wrap` class with the css property of `display: none`.

Sibling to this `.page-wrap` you could create the page that will appear once everything has loaded, the `.mature-content-warning` that will have a button to continue to view the website.

Once the user clicks the `.continue` button, the page will load in.

```
  <div class="page-wrap" style="display: none;">
    <h1>This is your site.</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="mature-content-warning">

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Mature Content Warning</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="lead">Are you 18 yrs old?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success continue" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

  </div>

  <!-- vendors -->
  <script src="vendors/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      });

      $('.continue').on('click', function() {
        $('.mature-content-warning').css('display', 'none');
        $('.page-wrap').fadeIn();
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to just trigger the visibility of the contents inside the .page-wrap element so it will appear once the modal starts loading?

Comment: i've updated my answer, the modal appears once the page has loaded, and the rest of the site appears once the modal is dismissed